# Nested array in Google Maps to make many Polygons

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an array:

```
[[[11.11,11.11],[22.22,22.22],[33.33,33.33]],[[11.11,11.11],[22.22,22.22],[33.33,33.33]]]
```

What I need to do in Javascript is beak each

> [[11.11,11.11],[22.22,22.22],[33.33,33.33]]

out and create a new Google Polygon.

I currently have the code below working for one polygon, it works fine but I am manually copy and pasting from the array to see if the code works, to be able to iterate over it automatically would be great to then create multiple polygons on the Google Map.

```
  var locs = [[51.4840407, -0.0318375], [51.4840351, -0.0306535], [51.4839436, -0.0300458],   [51.4840184, -0.0285545]]

 var latLng = []
 var point, _i, _len;
 for (_i = 0, _len = locs.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  point = locs[_i];
  latLng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(point[0], point[1]));
}
```

How can I take the array at the top, pull out each polygon and then draw it on to the map as separate polygons.

As per the first answer - I have reworked the code into:

```
var latLng =[]
var locs = []
for (var _p=0; _p < polys.length; _p++) {
    locs = polys[_p];
    for (_i = 0, _len = locs.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        point = locs[_i];
        latLng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(point[0], point[1]));
        bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [latLng]
        });

        bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

}
}
```

However when the polygon is drawn, they all "connect" as in they are treated as one - not as a separate polygon for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the second half of your requirement, so you only need to get each separate polygon into `locs` and then use that.

```
var polys = [[[11,11],[22,22],[33,33]],[[44,44],[55,55],[66,66]]];
for (var _p=0; _p < polys.length; _p++) {
    locs = polys[_p];
    // locs is [[11,11],[22,22],[33,33]] first time
    // locs is [[44,44],[55,55],[66,66]] second time
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you not need to define each polygon separately though for google maps to not join them up?

Comment: Or are you saying to iterate over each poly and draw within the loop?? So contains the google polygon draw call inside the loop?

Comment: Second one. That's what I thought you were doing.

Comment: ive updated my question to take account of your first answer - is this what you were meaning?

Comment: i will open a new question, as you have answered the original one thanks!